# Regex to avoid data duplication in delimited string?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I am trying to validate the data which will be `string` value with the `,` delimited. What I want is to validate that there should not be repetition of the same value within the `sting`.

Ex. my value would be.

```
    data1 = "value1,value2,value3,va-lu4,value 6,value1";//should fail
    data2 = "value1,value2,value3,va-lu4,value 6";//should pass
```

In above scenario `data1` should fail as it contains the `value1` twice. And in `data2` should pass or match as it doesnot contain any repeated value.

This is what I got for matching the each value but not sure how to check for the repetition.

```
    ^[-\w\s]+(?:,[-\w\s]*)*$
```

This will matches the values between delimiter but not sure how to check if duplicate values exist. Any help would be great.
**Note**- I know I can do this using the sting functions and loop bu I was learning the `Regex` and want to try if it is possible using the regex.In case of confusion feel free to comment AS this is my first question on Stack.

Comment: What **language** are you using? Because if the expression isn't compiled correctly it could lead to alot of catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: I am currently trying with `Javascript` but eventually I also want to try with the strct typed as `c#/Java` languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!(?:^|.*,)([^,\n]*),.*\1(?:,|$)).*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/24

Comment: What if it was `value1,value2,value2,va-lu4,value 6`

Answer (score 1):

**Regular expressions** are useful in many cases. But to **check duplicates** in a string can be achieved **easier** like this (in C#):

```
bool HasDuplicates(string str)
{
    var list1=str.Split(',').Select(s=>s.Trim());
    var list2=list1.Distinct();
    return (list1.Count()>list2.Count());
}
```

**How it works:** The function converts the string into a list, trims the elements and then creates a second distinct list from it. Finally it compares the number of elements in both lists: If the distinct list has less elements than the original list you have duplicates and the function returns true, else false.

**Example:**

```
var result1=HasDuplicates("Test1, Test1, Test2");
var result2=HasDuplicates("Test1, Test2, Test3");
```

The variable `result1` contains `true`, variable `result2` contains `false`.
You can try out the code in DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0pRURH

Comment: Yes I know. With string functions it is easy and it is good practice to use the string functions when complex string manipulations. But I was just trying to learn and when trying I am stumbled to this problem. Still Thanks.

Comment: That's fine, and there are a lot of cases where RegEx has advantages, which are usually when you're looking for complex patterns - such as the IP finder `((2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d\d?)`. By the way, there is a good 30 minute tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial), I hope it is useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for tutorial. I will definitely go through it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
^(?!.*(^|,)([^,]+),.*\2(,|$)).*
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/xNJR86L3k5)

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you explain which approch is better this or @vks ? And why ? That would help me to understand regex better. Thanks.

Comment: the main difference is that vks will treat a blank value  as matching another blank, eg `abc,,def,,ghi` is treated as having a duplicate, due to the capture group having a quantifier of `*` (*zero* or more). Vks also uses non-capturing groups `(?:...)`, which offer trivial performance benefits but IMHO make the regex harder to read .Vks also won't treat the newline as part of the value, but I don't think that's very relevant. Other than those points, the two regex's are very similar.